# How can I import layer symbology from another layer programmaticaly with ArcObjects & VBA?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, vba

I would like to be able to develop a procedure that runs through all layers in the TOC and if the layer (name) exists in a specific folder where I am storing layer files with complex symbology I would like to import the procedure to import the symbology from the layer files. I have a similar procedure for importing stored Label schema so combining the two into a more dynamic solution would save me a lot of time.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A while back, I wrote some VB code to persist and de-persist renderers in ArcObjects. It's a slightly different spin on your question but I think what you need is there. The code can be found at: http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=12474

I hope this helps.

Bill

Comment: Thanks Bill. I tried your script and just simply passed the path to the ".lyr" file as a parameter to the LoadRenderer procedure which raises an unspecified automation error. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: OK. It does work. When i create an ".agl" file  with the SaveRenderer procedure i can successfully load it into a layer.  Can i make this work with existing Layer Files?

Comment: I suppose I should explain the intent of the code. A .lyr file saves the data source information and everything else necessary to recreate an object that implements ILayer. We didn't need that; we just wanted to save the renderer. As a result, it starts lower down in the object hierarchy.

Comment: Here's a link to a discussion of handling .lyr files in C#: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=159&f=1705&t=134959#391529

Comment: To open .lyr files, you should just be able to use the LayerFile coClass (http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriCarto/ILayerFile.htm). With that, you can get at the layer through the ILayerFile.Layer property. You then need to cast it to an appropriate object (IGeoFeatureLayer for example) to get access to the Renderer property.