# How to set up graduated colors for a layer using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, symbology, arcgis-engine

I have to render a feature layer with a graduated colors renderer, using the ArcGIS API for Java (or VB, .NET).

As the feature layer data is created dynamically using webservices, I don't in advance the range of values, so I need to get the classification to be generated using the natural breaks algorithm.

Here is what I need to set:

[image: Layer properties window]

In addition, I need to get the largest values overlaying the smallest:

[image: Symbol level dialog]

I need to get n classes, using a AlgorithmicColorRamp from one given color to another color and symbolized by a simple line with a given width.

I tried to write this method, called after the layer data source is set:

```c#
    public static void applyGraduatedColorsLineRenderer(IGeoFeatureLayer geoFeatureLayer, String field, int count, IColor fromColor, IColor toColor, double width) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    IAlgorithmicColorRamp colorRamp = new AlgorithmicColorRamp();
    colorRamp.setAlgorithm(esriColorRampAlgorithm.esriCIELabAlgorithm);
    colorRamp.setFromColor(fromColor);
    colorRamp.setToColor(toColor);
    colorRamp.setSize(count);
    boolean[] ok = new boolean[1];
    colorRamp.createRamp(ok);

    ClassBreaksRenderer classBreaksRenderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer();
    classBreaksRenderer.setField(field);
    classBreaksRenderer.setBreakCount(count);
    classBreaksRenderer.setSortClassesAscending(false);
    classBreaksRenderer.setFlipSymbols(false);
    classBreaksRenderer.setColorRampByRef(colorRamp);

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        SimpleLineSymbol simpleLineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol();
        simpleLineSymbol.setColor(fromColor);
        simpleLineSymbol.setStyle(esriSimpleLineStyle.esriSLSSolid);
        simpleLineSymbol.setWidth(width);
        classBreaksRenderer.setSymbol(i, simpleLineSymbol);
    }

    geoFeatureLayer.setRendererByRef(classBreaksRenderer);
}
```

The problem is that I don't get the right range for my data, and the classification method is set to "manual" instead of "Natural Breaks":
[image]

Moreover, I don't know what is the equivalent in ArcObjects of checking "Draw this layer using the symbol levels specified below".

Comment: Not sure if this applies but perhaps you could use a template layer and import the symbology that way like in  [THIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-can-i-import-layer-symbology-from-another-layer-programmaticaly-with-arcobje) question.

Comment: It doesn't work as the symbology depends on the feature class data. So I think it needs to be generated for each new data programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe too late for an answer, but I think thats what you needed - the

[IClassBreaksUIProperties](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriCarto/IClassBreaksUIProperties.htm)

```
IClassify classifyMethod = new NaturalBreaksClass();
(classBreaksRenderer as IClassBreaksUIProperties).Method = classifyMethod.ClassID;
```

The checking "Draw this layer using the symbol levels specified below" you can also set with the UIProperties:
*IClassBreaksUIProperties.ShowClassGaps Property*